# Assembly Language invalid operand for offset

Tags: assembly, x86, syntax-error, masm, irvine32

Hi I am a computer science student and am making a code to input 20 names and grades and display them with colors relating to the letter grade. I got two similar errors and was wondering if someone could explain to me the problem and how I could fix it.

Here's the code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc



Student STRUCT
    myName BYTE 26 DUP(00h)
    myGrade BYTE 26 DUP(00h)
Student ENDS


.data
myClass Student 20 DUP(<>)
myNumber BYTE 3 DUP(00h)
nameQuestion BYTE "What is your name?",0dh,0ah,0
gradeQuestion BYTE "Please enter ",0
grade2Question BYTE "'s grade.",0dh,0ah,0
myName BYTE 26 DUP(00h)
myGrade BYTE 26 DUP(00h)
linebreak BYTE 0dh,0ah,0
comma BYTE ","
space BYTE " "
counter BYTE 0
.code
main PROC

R1: call Clrscr

    mov edx,OFFSET nameQuestion
    call WriteString

    mov edx,OFFSET myName
    mov ECX,26

    mov eax, SIZEOF Student
    mul myNumber
    mov esi,eax
    lea edx, (Student PTR myClass[esi]).myName 

    call ReadString

    cmp eax, 00h
    JE R2
    call Clrscr


R3: mov edx,OFFSET gradeQuestion
    call WriteString

    mov edx,OFFSET myName
    call WriteString

    mov edx,OFFSET grade2Question
    call WriteString

    mov edx,OFFSET myGrade
    mov ECX,26

    mov eax, SIZEOF Student
    mul myNumber
    mov esi,eax
    lea edx, (Student PTR myClass[esi]).myGrade

    call ReadString
    inc myNumber

L1: CMP myGrade, "A"
    JE R5
    CMP myGrade, "B"
    JE R5
    CMP myGrade, "C"
    JE R5
    CMP myGrade, "D"
    JE R5
    CMP myGrade, "F"
    JE R5
R5: inc counter
    CMP counter,20
    JNE R1  

R4: call Clrscr

    mov dh,3
    mov dl,5
    call Gotoxy

    mov eax, SIZEOF myClass
    mul counter
    mov esi, eax
91  lea edx, OFFSET (Student PTR myClass[esi]). myName
    call WriteString


J1: mov eax, 07h
    CMP myGrade, "D"
    JNE J2
    mov eax, 0Eh
J2: CMP myGrade, "F"
    JNE J3
    mov eax, 04h
J3: Call SetTextColor

    mov dh,3
    mov dl,32
    call Gotoxy


    mov eax, SIZEOF myClass
    mul counter
    mov esi, eax
112 lea edx, OFFSET (Student PTR myClass[esi]). myGrade
    call WriteString

    mov edx, OFFSET linebreak
    call WriteString

    mov eax, 07h
    Call SetTextColor

    call WaitMsg
    jmp R1
R2: exit
main ENDP

END main
```

and here is the error messages I received:

```
1>..\Code.asm(91): error A2071: initializer magnitude too large for specified size
1>..\Code.asm(91): error A2098: invalid operand for OFFSET
1>..\Code.asm(112): error A2098: invalid operand for OFFSET
```

Comment: OFFSET only works on build-time constant expressions.  I'm not sure what syntax MASM requires to express `lea edx, [esi + myClass + offset_of_myGrade_inside_Student]`.  Something like `lea edx, [esi + myClass]` should work (without OFFSET because it's part of an addressing mode, not an immediate), but I'm not how MASM's syntax for the offset of a member within a struct works.

Comment: Also note that `counter` is a BYTE, so `mul counter` will only do `ax = al * [counter]`, an 8x8 => 16-bit multiply, leaving the upper bits of EAX unmodified.  You probably want to just keep your counter in a register, or better keep a *pointer* in a register and increment it with `add esi, SIZEOF Student`.